# Responsive plolty output in Rmarkdown documents as in shiny apps

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown, responsive

I am trying to generate a fluid and responsive plotly output in a Rmarkdown document as I normally get in shiny apps, but by default the output overflow in small screens.

I need to know if I have to include any dependency to my Rmarkdown document, or activate any chunk option in order to make it work properly.

See the example below.

#### Shiny app

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      static <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = cyl)) +
          geom_point()
      
      ggplotly(static)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**The output is a html document with a responsive plot:**
[image]

#### Rmarkdown html document

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

static <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = cyl)) +
          geom_point()
      
      ggplotly(static)
````

The output is also a html document but without a responsive plot
[image]

Comment: I tried plotting the same plot using the code you provided and found that the output plot(static) is responsive.

Comment: Running the code in the console output a responsive plot in the viewer, but if you create an Rmakrdown document and knit it, the resulting html document is not.